# Assign images to two UIImageViews in a collectionViewCell from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview

I have a UICollectionView inside a UITableView. Inside the UICollectionView there are 2 imageViews in each cell.  UIImagePickerController is used to select the image when tapped on one of the imageViews.

I want the results to be - When I click on firstPhotoView of first cell and select an image that should be added to imageView of that particular cell and so on

With the below code, if I select an image that same image is getting added to both of the imageViews that are there in the cell.

How can I get the info about the cell that is tapped and assign image to the imageView that called the UIImagePicker ? Please suggest.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AntitipPhotoCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! AntitipPhotoCollectionCell
    
    
    cell.cameraIconTappedClosure = { [weak self] in
        if self?.imagePicker.sourceType == .camera {
            self?.present(self!.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if self?.imagePicker.sourceType == .photoLibrary {
            self?.present(self!.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        
    }
    if indexPath.row == photosArray.count - 1 {
       
            cell.firstPhotoView.image = photosArray[indexPath.item]
            cell.secondPhotoView.image = photosArray[indexPath.item]
        }
    
    return cell
```

}[enter image description here][1]

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

            guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else  {
                fatalError("Expected a image")
            }
            photosArray.append(image)
            for cell in servicesCheckListTableView.visibleCells {
                  let indexPath = IndexPath(item: photosArray.count-1, section: 0)
                 (cell as? ServicesCheckListableViewCell)?.antiTipPhotoCollectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
                (cell as? ServicesCheckListableViewCell)?.antiTipPhotoCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
    
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

Comment: Aren't you assigning the images to both `imageView`s yourself? Also (in the second piece of your code) if your datasource is already looking at `photosArray` using the conventional UICollectionViewDatasource delegate methods you don't have to manually insert cells right?

Comment: @Gee.E  Currently if I select an image, it is being assigned to both imageViews. I want to identify the cell and the imageView that selects the image and assign based on that.